# Is there any way to embed scene created with UE4 into WhatsApp and let the user Interact

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I created my scene with UE and ready to be deployed to the end-user. Which packaging should I use if I want to shown and to be interactable to end-user on WhatsApp?

I know that it may sound weird since embedding an executable into another application is clear violation of breaching into another system, it may bear notorious intentions.

But my intention is benignly to provide easy way of interaction with scene to the end user without loading any apk or executables. Is there any way of doing that, especially in WhatsApp?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a way to do this with the engine.  If by interact you mean just move around the scene there may be tools to move it to a file format that supports this.